# simple test program of MPI on cluster

Tags: c, file, openmpi, mpich

```
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*-------------------------------------*/
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define PERMS 0600
#define PAGE 4096

int ntask=0, mytask=0;

void
write_result (char *detail)
{
    int fd;

    char *filename = (char *) malloc (1000*sizeof(char));

    sprintf(filename, "%d", mytask);

    strcat(filename,".fa");

    fd = open (filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);

    write (fd, detail, strlen (detail));

    close (fd);
}

char *
mmaping (char *source)
{
    int src;
    char *sm;
    struct stat statbuf;

    if ((src = open (source, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {
        perror (" open source ");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fstat (src, &statbuf) < 0)
    {
        perror (" fstat source ");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("task->%d\n",mytask);
    printf("total task->%d\n",ntask);

    int piece = statbuf.st_size/PAGE;
    int share = piece/ntask;

    printf("share->%d\n",share);
    sm = mmap (0,statbuf.st_size/ntask, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE,src, mytask*share*PAGE);

    printf("%lld\n",(long long int) statbuf.st_size);

    if (MAP_FAILED == sm)
    {
        perror (" mmap source ");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return sm;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ntask);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mytask);

    char *x = mmaping(argv[1]);
    printf("%d\n",strlen(x));

    write_result(x);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Each thread reads one piece of a file and write it down.

Works perfectly fine on local machine (mpich)
Got error on cluster (openmpi)

My program terminated at close(fd) in function write_result.

Here is the error msg

```
[kalkyl3:30022] *** Process received signal ***
[kalkyl3:30022] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[kalkyl3:30022] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[kalkyl3:30022] Failing at address: 0x2b9d952d7000
[kalkyl3:30022] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x371900f4a0]
[kalkyl3:30022] [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6() [0x371892fcef]
[kalkyl3:30022] [ 2] ./a.out(write_result+0x58) [0x400df8]
[kalkyl3:30022] [ 3] ./a.out(main+0x4c) [0x400e6c]
[kalkyl3:30022] [ 4] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x371881ecdd]
[kalkyl3:30022] [ 5] ./a.out() [0x400ba9]
[kalkyl3:30022] *** End of error message ***
```

After searching the relevant problem, I am guessing that the problem may come from the file open and close process. A file which is opened by one specific thread should be closed by the same thread. Maybe openmpi doesn't recognize which thread opened it and which one closed it. But it works fine on MPICH.

Comment: Can you not use MPI-I/O http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node261.htm#Node261 ?